# Variable loses it's value once out of API call

Tags: angular

I just started to build my first AngularApp by myself. I have watched many tutorials over and over again. But I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

I have built apps with PHP and other languages in the past but it seems that Angular does things differently.

The problem is that I am declaring `my_var` at the start of my code. A couple of lines down I make an API call to get a list of items. I console log the `resp` and `my_var` values and it all looks good.
When I try to use `my_var` outside of the API 'loop', it just turns into undefined.

I know I am doing something wrong here. I suspect I have not yet understood how variable scopes work in Angular.

Here is the component code:

```
rvcs;

constructor(private productService: ProductService, public configService: ConfigService, private apis: APIsService) {}

ngOnInit() {
              
        this.apis.consultarRVCs().subscribe( resp => {
            this.rvcs = resp//stores RESP values - WORKS
            console.log('Value of RESP: ',resp)//prints RESP values - WORKS
            console.log('Value of variable after storing RESP values in it: ',this.rvcs)//prints the value insde this loop/api call - WORKS
          })
        
          
        console.log('Value of variable outside of API call: ',this.rvcs);//prints undefined - Doesn't WORK
```

Here is the API funcition in the Service file:

```
consultarPopularidadPorFechaIn(id_rvc,fecha_in) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.API_URL}/consultarReservaciones/${id_rvc}/${fecha_in}`);
  }
```

As you can see in this picture, the last console log is being printed as undefined before the API call. This is why I suspect it has something to do with variable scopes.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I have read through all of that but still can't get it to work

Comment: You can't call to order a pizza and then immediately start eating the pizza. You have to wait for the pizza to arrive.

Comment: I totally get that but how do I make it work then. Is there an alternative to subscribe?

Comment: If you need to do something immediately upon receiving the data, you do it in the `subscribe()` block. Otherwise you assign the result to a class property (as you're doing) and use it when you need it.

Comment: So I can't just have an API to get list of fruits, store them for later. Then an API to get list of veggies, store them for later. To ultimately, put them together and create recipe for a smoothie

Comment: Sure you can. You can use [`forkJoin()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin) on your two observables, and then subscribe to the result.

Comment: what issue you are facing due to this undefined. as js execute the code line by line and subscription to an observable will wait untill the api response came, while during this your outer code executes and print undefined.
tell us the exact issue which you are facing due to this undefined value.

Comment: that is async subscribe would not have completed when you are logging it after the call like that,

Comment: What I need is a way to get the info from my APIs without "waiting" and execute my code line by line and have it work as expected/written

Answer (score 1):

The code you are posting is correct, the results from the `console.log` are expected.

Angular uses `Observables` for handle a variety of common **asynchronous** operations. By default, `observables` are lazy, if you don't `subscribe` to them, you will not get the response from the http call in this case.

Once you subscribe, the code within the `subscribe` function becomes asynchronous, meaning, it will execute later.

```js
...
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('1');
  
    this.myService.getSomething().subscribe(() => console.log('2'));     

    console.log('3');
  }
}

// Output will be 1, 3, 2
```

You can read more about `observables` here: [link](https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular)

Comment: But how do I make it work. Is tehre a way to tell Angular to wait until the API info comes back and then continue with the rest of the code

Comment: @MarcusDeclementi what logic do you need to do once you get the HTTP response?

Comment: Here is what I need:

Call API to get List of BracnhOffices and store it for later use.
Call API to get List of Employees and store it for later use.

Ultimately call an API to put those 2 pieces of data together and upload them to SQL

Answer (score 0):

```
async ngOnInit(): void {
  // here console.log will be called only after wait anser from service func
  this.rvcs = await this.apis.consultarRVCs().toPromise().then().catch();
  console.log('Value of variable outside of API call: ',this.rvcs);//prints undefined - Doesn't WORK
}
```